# Access Efficiency of Static vs Stack-dynamic variables

Tags: c++, static

Have an assignment where I'm supposed to create two subprograms with three large arrays each (at least 100x100).  One is to be static and the other stack-dynamic, and "the code in the subprogram must perform a large number of matrix multiplication operations on the static matrices and time the process."  Similarly, it must do the same on the stack-dynamic as well.

From my understanding, working with static arrays should be much faster than stack-dynamic, but I am seeing different results.

```
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void staticMatrix();
void stackDynamicMatrix();

int main() {
    staticMatrix();
    stackDynamicMatrix();
    return 0;
}

void staticMatrix(){
    static int a[100][100];
    static int b[100][100];
    static int c[100][100];

    // Fill with random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            a[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 1;
            b[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 1;
        }
    time_t begin;
    time(&begin);
    // Do large number of matrix multiplications
    for (double k = 0; k < 300000; k++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                c[i][j] = a[i][j] * b[i][j];
            }
    time_t end;
    time(&end);

    cout<<"Time elapsed for Static: " << difftime(end, begin)<<endl;

    return;
}

void stackDynamicMatrix(){
    int d[100][100];
    int e[100][100];
    int f[100][100];

    // Fill with random numbers
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
            d[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 1;
            e[i][j] = rand() % 100 + 1;
        }
    time_t begin2;
    time(&begin2);
    // Do large number of matrix multiplications
    for (double k = 0; k < 300000; k++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                f[i][j] = d[i][j] * e[i][j];
            }
    time_t end2;
    time(&end2);
    cout<<"Time elapsed for Stack-Dynamic: " << difftime(end2, begin2)<<endl;

    return;
}
```

Upon running, I am seeing that `staticMatrix()` taking ~ 5sec, whereas the `stackDynamicMatrix()` is taking 0 sec (which doesn't sound right).

http://ideone.com/3WvdWy

If anyone can explain what I'm doing wrong or misunderstanding here, it would be appreciated.

Comment: Why would working with a static array be faster than working with one on the stack? I see no good reason to expect a significant difference.

Comment: @JerryCoffin: I see a pretty good reason for the difference he IS seeing -- the lifetime of the static result matrix isn't ending, the lifetime of the automatic result matrix is, so the compiler can optimize the latter away completely, along with all the loops feeding it.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Sorry, I probably should have been more clear. I was referring to real use in real code (or in a benchmark that went to some trouble to produce meaningful results).

Comment: In general (doing the exact same work) there could be a very small advantage to the automatic arrays.  Pages of the stack are fairly likely to be in cache already, and there's less chance of cache conflicts between the arrays and control data when they're laid out adjacent.  Any difference is almost certainly too small to be concerned about.

Comment: @JerryCoffin It depends on the architecture.  On a Sparc, it generally will take one less instruction to access a local variable compared to accessing a static.  On machines that don't have efficient based addressing (like the old 8080), accessing local variables could be significantly slower.  I suspect that most modern architectures are optimized for modern programming techniques, and accessing local variables will be at least as fast, if not faster, than accessing statics.

Comment: @JamesKanze: ...and people accuse me of impractical answers! I guess if there were a C++ compiler for an 8080, I might try to take them into account, but as-is, I'm pretty sure the speed of execution on an 8080 is precisely 0 for either one. In fact, the code above uses at least 60K just for `a`, `b` and `c`, and if memory serves my TPA under CP/M was around 53K, so the code above couldn't even have loaded (not to mention the stack was limited to 256 bytes, IIRC). :-)

Comment: @JerryCoffin I mentionned the 8080, because that's the first processor that came to mind with this particular characteristic.  Although it wasn't that rare back then.  I think it's also true of mainframe IBMs, possibly even today.

Comment: @JamesKanze: Yeah, in the end there are processors which could make a little difference, but this code seems to me to be caught between a rock and a hard place. If the data is large enough for `time`/`time_t`/`difftime` to measure it meaningfully, it's almost certain to be mostly in main memory, and the speed is pretty much going to depend on memory bandwidth, not the CPU. Otherwise, it's going to be fast enough that `difftime` will normally return 0 or 1, and isn't telling you anything about actual speed.

Comment: @JamesKanze: I guess, maybe, on something like an 8088 or possibly PDP/11 (no cache, slow enough CPU to see differences from instructions instead of memory bandwidth) you might be able to get the code to execute and still get execution slow enough to get a meaningful result, but even there I wouldn't be very certain. On a machine new enough to even find it in a dumpster nowadays, it seems pretty doubtful.

Comment: @JerryCoffin Certainly, such differences are of more historical interest than anything else.  As you say, on any modern processor, for anything but the smallest arrays, memory band width will swamp any other differences in timing.  Similarly, for anything but the smallest arrays, the locality aspects raised by Ben Voigt will be irrelevant.

Answer (score 1):

You are experiencing a few common mistakes when running benchmarks:

- Inaccurate timers
- Too much release optimizations
- Only running one test

Running your code unmodified (except for a more accurate timer) in MSVC 2010 in debug/release builds gets me:

- Debug Static = 7900 ms
- Debug Stack-Dynamic = 9500 ms
- Release Static = 1900 ms
- Release Stack-Dynamic = 420 ms

First, you need to use a timer with more precision to get more meaningful results. In Windows for quick benchmarks I usually use `GetTickCount()` but a more accurate one would be `QueryPerformanceCounter()`. Or use the C++11 standard `std::chrono::high_resolution_clock` if you have a compatible compiler.

From the debug/release times you can see that the optimizer is smart enough to reduce most of the stack-dynamic case to nothing. It "knows" that you never use the result of the for loops and can eliminate all or most of them.

In order to get a meaningful benchmark you have to "trick" the compiler into not optimizing such loops away. I usually do something like:

```
void stackDynamicMatrix() {
    size_t Sum = 0;
    ...

    for (double k = 0; k < 300000; k++)
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
                c[i][j] = a[i][j] * b[i][j];
                Sum += c[i][j];             //Added
            }

    ...
    cout < <"Sum = " << Sum << endl;   //Be sure to output result
}
```

That way the compiler is forced (usually) do keep the loops in. Note that sometimes the compiler is too smart and can optimize away this partially or fully. Of course, to be fair you add the `Sum...` to all benchmarks whether they need it or not.

With the addition of the sums I get the following results in a release build:

- Static = 2400 ms
- Stack-Dynamic = 2400 ms

Each times are well within the natural variation of the benchmark times. While it doesn't affect this particular benchmark much, I would also do:

```
int main() {
    staticMatrix(); //Ignore this result
    staticMatrix();
    staticMatrix();
    staticMatrix();
    stackDynamicMatrix(); //Ignore this result
    stackDynamicMatrix();
    stackDynamicMatrix();
    stackDynamicMatrix();
    return 0;
}
```

and ignore the first benchmark in each test. Sometimes caching can mess up the first benchmark result (unless that is what you are trying to measure).